# how to get the next three events from mysql database starting with closest date to today

Tags: mysql, date

I'm connecting to my MySQL database using the PDO method. i have events stored with event_date as a date type. how do i select the 3 next events after today's date? do i need to switch event_date from date to a timestamp? I keep my dates stored in this format yyyy-mm-dd and they have to be like that for other parts of code to work.

i tried this but it didnt really work:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE event_date > NOW()
ORDER BY event_date ASC
LIMIT 3
```

pretty new to pdo and im not good with date and time functions in general :/ thanks!

Comment: What data type is the event_date column now? What do you mean by "it didnt really work?" Didn't work how? What did you expect, and what did you get?

Comment: I think it should do what you want, but what do you really expect as result ? and what you get with this query ?

"format yyyy-mm-dd" I hope you use The DATE type... you must in your case.

Comment: @Nick Please post some sample data that gives you the unexpected/undesired result with your query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(curdate(),event_date) as closetevent 
   from events 
   Order by closetevent ASC 
   LIMIT 3
```